# Android Listview OnClickListener not working

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview, android-fragments

My problem is when i click list item in main layout some time it's triggered but not all time.
I don't know how to solve this problem?.
Please help me..

My code is:

```
View v = convertView.findViewById(R.id.chat_window_single);
v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.i("position",v.getTag().toString());
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
        editor.putLong("eventId", groupEventMoList.get(Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().toString())).getEventId());
        editor.putString("eventTitle",groupEventMoList.get(Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().toString())).getText());
        editor.commit();
        Intent groupAct = new Intent(context, GroupChatActivity.class);
        startActivity(groupAct);
    }

});
```

My layout file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/chat_window_single"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:clickable="false"
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/chat_title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5sp"
    android:shadowDx="1"
    android:shadowDy="1"
    android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light"
    android:textSize="20sp" >
</TextView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/event_place"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5sp"
    android:shadowDx="1"
    android:shadowDy="1"
    android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light"
    android:textSize="20sp" >
</TextView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/event_date"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5sp"
    android:shadowDx="1"
    android:shadowDy="1"
    android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light"
    android:textSize="20sp" >
 </TextView>

 </LinearLayout>
```

My main layout file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/chat_list_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="80dp" >

</ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Any Help  would be appreciated.

Comment: You have to use onItemClickListener instead of Onclicklistener

Comment: post your listview click lisener code. and use linerlayout instead of view. in getview method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your textviews are stealing the focus from parent list view, make them `clickable` and `focusable = false` also the upermost linear layout needs `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"`

Comment: your text views are still `clickable=true`

Comment: why not using `onItemClickListener` for ListView ?